# How to persist changes to details in a master/detail scenario

Tags: wpf, mvvm, asp.net-web-api

I feel this should be pretty simple, but I'm new to WPF and MVVM and just can't figure it out where to do it using MVVM. I've searched around for wpf+master+detail+mvvm but none of the examples I've found persists the data back to a database / webservice, which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Where should I place my call to my Web API using HttpClient in MVVM? I'd like to call the Web API when the user makes changes to the TodoModel's Text property, e.g. `PUT http://webapi.example.com/todos/5` with request body like `{ "Text":"This text is updated" }`

Model:

```
public class TodoModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="TodoMvvm.TodoView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TodoMvvm"
        Title="TodoView" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:TodoViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="TodoListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Todos}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTodo}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TodoTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedTodo.Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TodoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<TodoModel> Todos { get; set; }

    private TodoModel _selectedTodo;
    public TodoModel SelectedTodo 
    {
        get 
        { 
            // This triggers when changing the todo text, but it feels wrong to post changes back to the web api in a getter?!
            return _selectedTodo; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedTodo = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTodo"); 
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TodoModel> GetTodoModels()
    {
        // Todo models should be retrieved from a web api.
        var todos = new ObservableCollection<TodoModel>();
        todos.Add(new TodoModel { Id = 1, Title = "Lorem", Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" });
        todos.Add(new TodoModel { Id = 2, Title = "Consectetur", Text = "Consectetur adipisicing elit" });
        todos.Add(new TodoModel { Id = 3, Title = "Sed", Text = "Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua" });

        return todos;
    }

    public TodoViewModel()
    {
        Todos = GetTodoModels();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is not an attempt to answer this question, but an attempt to explain to the question author that their question is off topic for this website.

You are getting WPF confused with data persistence... the two are totally unrelated.

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) is a next-generation presentation system for building Windows client applications with visually stunning user experiences.

On the other hand:

> A persistent data structure is a data structure that always preserves the previous version of itself when it is modified

It seems to me as though you are asking how to save your hierarchical data, in which case, WPF is totally irrelevant to this question.

That just leaves the topic of *how do I save my hierarchical data?* In my opinion, that is far too broad in scope for a question on this website, as there are so many ways to save data. To continue with this question, you need to ask a specific programming related question that can actually be answered.

---

UPDATE >>>

Now understanding that you want to know where to place your data access code, I can continue. However, you will notice that there is no DA (for Data Access) in MVVM. MVVM is a development methodology, or an architectural pattern and it does not prescribe any particular method of data access to be used.

Having said that and from a more standard development point of view, it is customary to separate your data access layer from your UI layer (your V in MVVM), your business data model layer (your M in MVVM) and business logic (your VM in MVVM). This separation could be using folders in a small application, or projects in a larger application. This is called [separation of concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns).

---

Final UPDATE >>>

Where you put your code is completely up to you. As already stated, there are no rules in MVVM that specify where you must access your data, whether it comes from a web service, or a database, or a simple text file on a hard drive.

Obviously, the data has to pass through the view model at some stage, so the two most likely places to find web service code in a WPF Application is

a) directly in the view model, or
b) in a service class that is referenced by the view model.

However, as this is just my opinion and others will have different opinions, there can be no single correct answer to your question. That is exactly why these types of subjective questions are considered off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is not a question about saving the data. My Web API is working and I can persist data using it from say Fiddler. I'm wondering where I should place the call to my web API in the MVVM architecture. I've tried to rephrase the question a bit to emphasis this.

Comment: Comment to update: I've already separated my concerns and feel it's made clear in the question. In the question, I mention my presentation layer (the WPF application using MVVM) and my application layer (Web API). Below the application layer there are others layer, like the data access layer.

Basically I just want to know where in MVVM you'd be calling/consuming web services.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you've solved your problem by now, but in the interest of helping others who might come along later, I'll give it a shot.  There are a number of ways to go about this (of course).

In all cases you should probably put your data fetch and persist code into one class (or a facad pattern, interface, or some such thing) for a number of reasons.

You could put a "Save" button somewhere.  I'm just saying it's an option...   :)

**Simple Solution to a Simple Problem.**
The basic problem is that your "detail view" is too directly bound to the master.  For this simple example, your solution, which you say "feels wrong", is probably the best, because any other solution adds complexity that may not be useful.  In a really simple app I think it is fine to put up with some code smells.  If I am just going for an hour long hike through the woods, nobody is going to care if I wear my dirty, smelly boot socks.  I don't want to have to wash them before going for this short hike.

**More Complex Solution.**
I am working on a project with a TreeView (master) and a DetailViewer (detail) displaying different UserControls based on the data type of the item selected in the TreeView.  Instead of directly binding the DetailViewer to the TreeView, the TreeView is bound to a ViewModel (tvVM).  And each item in the TreeView is bound to an item ViewModel (itemVM).  The DetailViewer is bound to the itemVM when the selected item changes in the TreeView.  So, everything ends up being bound to a ViewModel and not directly to a Model.

Now.  At some point you'll need code to change which detail data is displayed (again, instead of having it directly bound).  I use an event handler triggered when the IsSelected property changes on the itemVM.  Then, I simply persist the data asynchronously.  [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1205636/How-to-make-selecteditemchanged-event-to-work-in-t) is an article that explains how to do this.

**Another option** would be to wait until the app is closing, or some other useful event, to save your data.  This may not be practical in a lot of situations.